# Is it possible to pre-render complex components in a separate thread in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a calendar in React Native, and the month view can be complex and takes some time to render.  It's not bad when viewing just one month, but I need to pre-render 6-12 months to have them ready if the user swipes to change months.

Ideally I would like to render the current month and display it, then in a separate thread pre-render several other months.

Is something like this possible in React Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current version of RN, this is only possible with a native component.

Imagine you want to pre-render 12 different month components in React. First, create a Month component in React that does not rely on any global state. Then, write a [native UI component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios) called `MultithreadedRenderer`. This component would be written twice, in Objective-C and in Java, and it would that bootstrap and create 12 separate `RCTBridge`, each with its own RCTRootView.<sup>1</sup> (If you use MultithreadedRenderer in multiple places in your app, it might be a good idea to keep these React Views around in a freelist.)

To finish it all off, you can embed the MultithreadedRenderer component within a normal React view-- pass props through MultithreadedRenderer.

Since each `RCTBridge` will be in a separate instance of React Native, you won't be able to change global state -- changes to global state in each in each month component will be isolated to that month component.

See my other answer for another alternative solution.

<sup>1</sup> By creating 12 separate `RCTBridge`s, you separately load the bundle and initialize each month as a new react view. Since each RCTBridge has its own Javascript engine thread, this will make your application multithreaded.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect this is the correct answer although I was hoping for a JavaScript-only solution since we are using Expo.  I'm guessing there isn't a way to do it in JavaScript only.

Comment: @LukeEhresman Just bite the bullet and eject your project, you can keep using expo. You don't need to learn Objective-C or Java to do this-- you just have to write enough of it to get that teensy bit of code written. Plus, once you've coded it, you can put it online and have others maintain it, so others can have a pure JS solution. I'd be glad to maintain such a project.

Comment: React Native is not a platform. It is a way to avoid re-writing code for both iOS and Android. You will feel pain if you try to do it all in the "react-native-y" way. RN is merely a thin abstraction layer, that is easy to break down towards the lower level. RN is not for people who want to code an okay mobile app with JS (see Cordova), RN is people who want to save time while coding a high-quality mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a `<FlatList>` component which can be customized very well.

Take a look at [this official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)

You can use `initialNumToRender` and `windowSize`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This wouldn't solve the problem though.  It's not that I don't want to render them initially.  I *do* want to render them initially so the views are ready when the user swipes left or right.  I just want them to render on a separate thread so it doesn't slow down the initial display of the first month.

Comment: @LukeEhresman 1. " just want them to render on a separate thread so it doesn't slow down the initial display of the first month." If that's true, you can just use `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` so that your latter months are pre-rendered and cached after the first month. 2. Also, are you sure it's even the JavaScript execution that's making your app slow? That would be the only case multithreading would really help. Are you sure it's not some backend fetch or the rendering?; Sounds like your initial question is suffering from http://xyproblem.info Ask good question get good answer

Comment: @LukeEhresman " just want them to render on a separate thread so it doesn't slow down the initial display of the first month. " If that's actually what you want, you're asking the wrong question, because there is certainly a way to say "after this view renders, pre-render this one" in regular React Native. Multithreading ≠ Asynchrony ≠ Concurrency. I assume you are an engineer, so you must devise technical solutions. No one will give you them for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could try porting [Nexus.js](https://github.com/voodooattack/nexusjs), a fork of WebKit's JavaScript engine JavaScriptCore, to iOS and Android and React Native. It has built-in multithreading support through async/await.